# Error in doctrine model

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with my doctrine model. When I call him I have an error and I don't know why...

My entity:

```
namespace Dimi\YvmBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Download
 *
 * @ORM\Table("t_download")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Dimi\YvmBundle\Entity\DownloadRepository")
 */
class Download extends EntityRepository
{


    public function getLastDownload()
    {

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $query->select('d')
            ->from('DimiYvmBundle:Download', 'd')
            ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('d.ytId');


        $query->setMaxResults(48);
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    }

}
```

TopController.php :

```
 public function getLastDownload()
    {

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');

        $query->select('d')
            ->from('DimiYvmBundle:Download', 'd')
            ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('d.ytId');


        $query->setMaxResults(48);
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
```

Error:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in /var/www/site/main.site/Symfony2/src/Dimi/YvmBundle/Controller/TopController.php on line 28 and defined in /var/www/site/main.site/Symfony2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php line 67
```

Do you know how I can fix that's ?

Thanks you all for your helping.
Best regards,

EDIT:

**I have resolved my problem, with doctrine if you want to create your custom query you have to write them into the myentitiRepository.php, not directly in myentity.php.**

Comment: Please show me your `TopController.php` around 28 line.

Comment: So, probably problem is with `$em = $this->getEntityManager();`. Try remove that line and change `$query = $em->createQueryBuilder();` to `$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');`. Let me know if it's working after changes : )

Comment: Oh, I nodiced that you forgot about an alias parameter for `createQueryBuilder()` method. So please add alias like `createQueryBuilder('q')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming this is Doctrine 2 and that your posted Download entity code is accurate?

You have: class Download extends EntityRepository which is just plain wrong.

Entities do not extend repositories.  Two completely different objects.

You should have:

```
/ **
  * Download Entity
  *
  * @ORM\Table("t_download")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Dimi\YvmBundle\Entity\DownloadRepository")
 */
class Download
{
    /* @Id */
    protected $id;

    /* Other property mappings */
```

and

```
class DownLoadRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    // Your custom queries
```

And yes, your query building code needs some work.  But get your entity and repository in separate classes first.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all you have to define query alias for `createQueryBuilder()` method like `-createQueryBuilder('q');`. Next, you should rather use shorter notation: `$this->createQueryBuilder();` instead `$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();`.

Compare: [`getEntityManager()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#229-235) and [`createQueryBuilder($alias)`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#68-79)

Moreover, you should get your `Download` repository via `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundleBundle:Download')` in your controller. When you call `new Download()` construct method of extended [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#___construct) is called too and it's makes error.

As @Cerad wrote - [Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class) and [Repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) are separate classes. In your controller after correctly got Repository class you can call each method simple:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundleBundle:Download');
$result = $repository->myCustomMethod();
```

Comment: @Dimi I updated my answer - you got your repository in wrong way.

Comment: I have modified that in my controller but do you know how I can call my entity method from my controller ?

`$lasdl= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DimiYvmBundle:Download')->getLastDownload();` ?